# If the time still, where is the eaten mass?

Tags: black-holes, mass, time-dilation

If I have a huge mass object, where around it the time is delayed and throw on it a stone:
In normal conditions, without the time dilation, the stone falls on the object, and its mass increases, I can see the stone falling and can measure the mass increase of the object.
In the time dilation case, the more the stone gets closer to the object slower it moves. But if the time still, I can't see the stone reach the object, and the object mass is not increased.

So, from outside a black hole, where is the eaten mass? in the center of the object or it is still around it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can anything ever fall into a black hole as seen from an outside observer?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21319/how-can-anything-ever-fall-into-a-black-hole-as-seen-from-an-outside-observer)

Comment: From the [highest voted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21431/) there: "the black-hole-with-an-essentially-undetectable-object-just-outside-its-event-horizon is a very good approximation to a black hole of a slightly larger mass"

Comment: @Jonas: They are perfect, answer all my doubts.